# How do I seal this grating when it rains?

Tags: drainage

[image]

I use this 6x10' grating for sunlight and aeration but its a menace when it rains. I have used multiple plastic sheets and tarpaulins. They do block the rainwater but start leaking or tearing apart after a few months. What are some permanent measures that I could take to fix this. Also, is there any automated method to do this when required.

Comment: What is the grate set into? What slope does it have?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no glass to keep rain out and the window is open all year except when you put plastic over it. If you prefer to have no glass, I am sure there is a producer of automatic louvers that have a rain sensor to sense when they need to close. They may shade the window more than the grate does now, but it will keep the rain out.I am sure the shade will be custom made for each window.

Comment: This would eliminate the need for the grating...